# Angular: When loading a component, the data is giving me undefined

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, angular6

I hesitate to ask this because I know the answer is going to be something incredibly obvious that is staring me in the face, but after 2 days of fighting with the code, I'm about to pull my hair out.

I am new to angular (just FYI) but not unfamiliar with the concepts behind it. I've built a small application that is attempting to read data from an API hosted on another server (potentially) which sends me back a json object. This object then populates the component. Here's some sample code:

**page service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { HttpErrorHandler, HandleError } from './http-error-handler.service';
import { AlcalaPage } from '../../shared/models/alcala-page.model';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders( {
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
  })
};

@Injectable()
export class PageService {
  pageServiceUrl: string;
  private handleError: HandleError

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private httpErrorHandler: HttpErrorHandler) {
    this.pageServiceUrl = environment.apiUrl + 'page/';
    this.handleError = httpErrorHandler.createHandleError('PageService');
  }

  getPage(pageid: string): Observable<AlcalaPage> {
    return this.http.get<AlcalaPage>(this.pageServiceUrl + pageid)
      .pipe(
          tap(data => console.log('Data is ' + data.months[0].expenses[0].entryType)),
          catchError(this.handleError('getPage', null))
        );
  }
}
```

**page.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

import { AlcalaPage } from '../../shared/models/alcala-page.model';
import { PageService } from '../service/page.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page',
  templateUrl: './page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page.component.scss']
})
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {
  pageid: string;
  imageurl: string;
  dataModel: AlcalaPage;
  public apiData;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private pageService: PageService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.pageid = params['id'];
    });
    this.getPage();
    this.imageurl = environment.imageUrl + this.pageid + '.jpg';
  }

  getPage(): void {
    this.pageService.getPage(this.pageid)
      .subscribe(
        data => { this.dataModel = data; },
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('page data loaded.')
        );
  }
}
```

**page.component.html**

```
<div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap="0.5%" fxLayoutAlign="left">
  <div fxFlex="70%">
    <h2 class="right-align">{{dataModel.year}}</h2>
    <mat-tab-group>
      <mat-tab label="English">
        <div *ngFor="let month of dataModel.months">
          <app-month [dataModel]="month" currentLang="en"></app-month>
        </div>
      </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Spanish">
        <div *ngFor="let month of dataModel.months">
          <app-month [dataModel]="month" currentLang="es"></app-month>
        </div>
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="20%">
    <ngx-imageviewer [src]="this.imageurl"></ngx-imageviewer>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem seems to stem from the lifecycle of the page and my (obvious) misunderstanding of how the lifecycle moves. As of right now, the year field on the page is loading (`<h2 class="right-align">{{dataModel.year}}</h2>`) and the tab group is displaying it's header (so I see a tab for "English" and a tab for "Spanish" but nothing else is loading. When I inspect the console, I see an error message that states cannot read property "months" of undefined. I find this error message confusing for two reasons:

1. dataModel (of which months is a member) is obviously not undefined since I was able to render dataModel.year in the  tag.
2. dataModel.months definitely has data in it as I am able to write out various values to the console when the service loads the data from the server (I played around with logging a number of different properties of the json object to the console so I could ensure all my data was present).

My guess is that either a) I'm doing something wrong in the *ngFor loop in the  tags or b) I've missed something in the page lifecycle. But I have no idea what I might be doing wrong as all the tutorials I've followed and looked at seem to doing things the way I've implemented. Anyone that has any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's loaded async, so initially it will be undefined. Try doing `let month of dataModel?.month` instead, which will only read `month` is `dataModel` has been set: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Comment: Thanks! That fixed my issue. If you could post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: No probs, I've posted it as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's loaded async, so initially it will be undefined.

Try doing `let month of dataModel?.month` instead, which will only read `month` if `dataModel` has been set: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Comment: I also figured out I could wrap the everything in the component inside a `<div *ngIf="dataModel"> ... </div>` and that also took care of the issue (in case anyone was curious for another method). Thanks again for the input!